# How can I sort a list of strings to display "x number of characters"?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of several thousand strings [numbers formatted as text] of length 15 that all consist of "zeroes" and "ones." I want to filter and display only the results that contain "x number of zeroes" where x is a population of zeroes distributed across the string. **For example**, Show only the strings that contain exactly four zeroes in any arrangement. I've done this before, but cant remember how exactly I typed my conditions into the filter menu. I may have used a 'contains and contains' filter.

Answer (score 2):

At first create a new column with this formula:

```
=LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"0",""))
```

With this formular you can find out how many zero characters are in the String.

In the second step you have to filter your table:

1. Click on Start
2. Click on Filter
3. Filter the new column to show only lines with a specific number of characters